# What is the status of the 'default props rerender' trap in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm looking for a canonical reference to how this has been dealt with.

If I have a component that looks like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({ value = [] }) => {
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOtherValue(value);
  }, [value]);


  return <div> doesn't matter</div>
};
```

What happens is:

1. When `value` changes, the useEffect callback fires, and this calls a setState
2. The setState causes a rerender, if `value` is nullish, then the default array is assigned, and this is a *new* object, and so this in turn, causes a rerender.
3. Infinite loop.

The solution can be to declare your default prop as a constant, like:

```
const DEFAULT_VALUE = []; 
const MyComponent = ({ value = DEFAULT_VALUE }) => {
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState([]);
```

My questions:

For each of the version 16, 17, 18 of React:

- Is this an issue that has been solved? If, so which version solved it?
- If it hasn't been solved, a pointer to the 'won't solve' decision.
- Is there an eslint rule to capture this?
- Anything else that is generally helpful in avoiding this trap.

Comment: I dont know it it answer you general question, but in this specific scenario i would skip useEffect and just pass value to useState: `const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState(value);` this will skip that rerender which causing infinite loop

Comment: @Wraithy - that's not what I'm asking. What if that `useEffect` has some expensive  conversion logic, that we only want to fire when the `value` updates?

Also, straight `useState`  won't work. The state will only be set first render, if value later updates, the `useState` hook won't know about it.

Comment: Dear @dwjohnston, thanks for your awesome question, actually, the best answer is your answer, for `reference` values in the default value of destructuring assignment we must use cached var. thanks. I will add another answer that point to this.

Comment: I haven't seen an infinite loop, unless you add `otherValue` to the useEffecte dependency array. You should been testing and ensuring the `value` is of type array. Whichever function that made `value` nullish in the parent component, should take up the responsibility of ensuring it's `[]`. Anyway if `value` is `null, `otherValue` will become `null` (not the default value of `[]`), and there won't be another rerender unless explicitly asked to do so.

Comment: Personally I deal with it by setting the default value inside of the `useEffect`.  Like `React.useEffect(() => { setOtherValue((value || []).map(v => ...)); }, [value]);` and allowing `value` itself to be possibly `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

The infinite loop is not related to `ReactJS`, so it couldn't be fixed by any versions. the issue returns to [`primitive/reference`](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-primitive-vs-reference-values/) values.

When you are using this:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ value = [] }) => {
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOtherValue(value);
  }, [value]);
```

For even one change from props, if the next `value` is `undefined` javascript create a new value `[]` and assign it to `value` and `React.useEffect` thinks it's new (actually this thought is correct) and tries to get the new prop and compare with the last one and for any of these actions use `value` and each time it is new because its reference is new.

But your solution is awesome, for any `reference type` values we must cache it and then use it to avoid creating it over and over:

```js
const DEFAULT_VALUE = []; 
const MyComponent = ({ value = DEFAULT_VALUE }) => {
```

**ESLint**:

There are some plugin rules to force developers to add default values in required or not-required props, but none of them hints you to cache the reference-type values for default props.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a property called defaultProps. With defaultProps the default value of your property become part of the definition the component and is no longer reseted at every render, preventing the infinity loop with useEffect. So it will be something like that:

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setOtherValue(value);
  }, [value]);


  return <div> doesn't matter</div>
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  value: []
};
```

And yes, there is an lint rule for that, but the rule is:

> Enforce a defaultProps definition for every prop that is not a required prop

So it is not exactly what you want because it works with prop-types rules but I think will help you with it. If you wanna see more details about this rule [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md) is the readme describing it.

Comment: Definitely a valid answer. One of the problems with default props is that it doesn't behave nicely with TypeScript, and so I tend to not use it.

Comment: defaultProps depreciation notice is already out, so you should avoid using defaultProps - https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/16210

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but why you dont add a validation to test if the array exist and in that case set the internal component state?

Use of `defaultProps` will be deprecated soon:
https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1133878326358171650

```html
const MyComponent = ({ value = [] }) => {
  const [otherValue, setOtherValue] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (value !== null) setOtherValue(value); // could be: value?.length > 0
  }, [value]);


  return <div> doesn't matter</div>
};
```

One other way I think about is using de `||` operator:

```html
const MyComponent = (props) => {
   const value = props.value || [];
   ...
};
```

Comment: Your second approach has the same problem as the original question - it's declaring a a new object each render.